# File permission reset after reboot with Lubuntu/PCmanFM

Tags: permissions, lubuntu, pcmanfm

I am changing file permission with

```
chmod a+w /var/run/btsync.debconf-default.pid
```

and it works. After a reboot i get:

```
service btsync start
* Autostarting btsync instance 'debconf-default'                               
start-stop-daemon: unable to open pidfile '/var/run/btsync.debconf-default.pid' for writing (Permission denied)
* Failed to start btsync instance debconf-default - please check the configuration file /etc/btsync/debconf-default.conf
```

Also tried with root / sudo etc.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Changed permission with gksu pcmanfm with right-click to the file and changed to owner. For one reboot it worked fine. After the second reboot everything is like in the first place. Owner is root again and btsync cant write the file.